# install react-native-video cant link

Tags: react-native

I install react-native-video by yarn,
when I install success,I use command 'react-native link',but failed,
so I link the files manually:
reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video android part;

when it done,I use command 'react-native run-android',show this info:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-video'.

> Java 8 language support, as requested by 'android.enableD8.desugaring= true' i
>   n your gradle.properties file, is not supported when 'android.useDexArchive= fal
>   se'.
>   ...
>   Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

can somebody help me to find out the problem?thank you so much
by the way,my react-native version is '0.58.6'.

Comment: This version does not require a link to be run.

Comment: so how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Simply install the module and run it according to the usage.